# 64 Bit Android compiling but has problems at runtime

Tags: c++, android-ndk, 64-bit

I have an Android App with a big C++ library which runs smoothly when compiled for

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a  //32 bit
```

but has issues when compiled with

```
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a   //64 bit
```

All JNI jint variables have been converted to jlong variables according to the NDK docs.

My problem is that for some reason I can not compare variables of any data type other than int when they are assigned from a function varible.

This works:

```
unsigned long a = 200;
unsigned long b = 200;
if(a == b) {
    LOGE("got here"); //This works
}
```

This fails:

```
void myClass::MyFunction(unsigned long c, unsigned long d) {
    if(c == d) {
        LOGE("got here"); //This does NOT work
    }
}
```

Mind you, both above functions work in the 32 bit build. The values that I read from the variables c and d are identical when logged.

Interestingly this works in the 64 bit version (int variables):

```
void myClass::MyFunction(int e, int f) {
    if(e == f) {
        LOGE("got here"); //This works
    }
}
```

Only integers can be compared. I have tried long, double, long long, unsigned and signed...

My NDK version is 10d (latest). I have tried with both, the 32 and 64 bit versions of the NDK and the result is the same. My development platform is a Win7 64 bit desktop.

Am I missing somethign essential?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit library or 64-bit library when building the 64-bit versions?  There could be issues linking a 32-bit library to a 64-bit application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I've actually tried both and the result is the same. My machine is 64 bit Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to my problems:

Data type sizes are different on 64 bit so my library was expecting 4 byte but longs are 8 bytes (4 bytes when compiled for 32 bit). Typecasting them to uint32_t did the trick.

Normal int worked because thats 4 bytes by default.